Supabase aggregate SUM on nested table return single result
In Supabase I have two tables, invoices and invoice_items, where invoice_items have a total column which represents the total for that item on an invoice, i.e. includes tax
Im trying to write a query that returns all invoices, with a calculated total for each invoice by running sum()on the invoice's item's totals
With an example of a single invoice, id = 1, and two invoice_items with totals of 5000 and 1300
Ive tried a few things but im currently at -
await supabase
    .from("invoices")
    .select(
      `        
        id,
        total:invoice_items(sum:total.sum())
    `,
    )

which feels close, but the result is in the format -
[{
    "id": '1',
     "total":[{
        "sum":6300
     }]
}]

but im trying to achieve (if possible) -
[{
    "id": '1',
     "total": 6300
}]

Is it possible, and any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
